# Joining two tables to get max login time of person

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One for Customer and other is for managing login history. Now what I want to do is to get the customer name and email from customer table, and last login time from loghistory table.

I have used the query:

```
select cust_email, login_time, cust_email
from customer
left join login on customer.cust_id = login.cust_id
GROUP by cust_id
```

It gives me the correct result showing NULL for the customers who never logged in, but gives the first login time of other customers not the latest one. How do I get the last login time of customer?

Comment: max(login_time)

Comment: Note that your current query is not actually guaranteed to give you the first `login_time`, and under many database systems and configurations would just give you an error, because you haven't specified which `login_time` you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `max()` function

```
   select cust_email,max(login_time) as max_login_time from customer
   left join login on customer.cust_id=login.cust_id
   GROUP by cust_email
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX()` & columns which are in `SELECT` statement must be aggregated or it should be with `GROUP BY` clause :

```
select c.cust_email, max(l.login_time)
from customer c left join 
     login l
     on c.cust_id = l.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_email;
```

Note : Use table `alias` that is easy to understand & read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use simple "Join" not left join with a order by clause. Try this:

```
select cust_email, login_time, cust_email
from customer
join login on customer.cust_id = login.cust_id
GROUP by cust_id
Order by login_time esc
```

Comment: AFAIK `JOIN` is the same as `INNER JOIN`.